# Combine media queries

Tags: css

I have media queries depending on devices I.E

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) {
  //iphone x
  ...some css
 }

@media only screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  //iphone 6,7,8
    ... same css as iPhone x
  }

@media only screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  //iphone 6/7/8 plus
... same css again
}

etc..
```

As you can see I repeat code multiple times because for some reason I can't merge media queries, I tried:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) {
  ...some css
 }
```

Combining iPhone X with iPhone 6,7,8 queries, but does not work for iPhone 6,7,8. Is it possible to combine all of them if I use the same CSS rules? Regards

Comment: `@media only screen and (device-width: 375px and device-height: 812px and device-width: 375px and device-height: 667px) {`

Comment: use a comma to combine multiple media queries into a single rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comma to combine multiple [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) into a single rule.

Here is [MDN's definition of the `,` (comma) in media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#comma):

> Commas are used to combine multiple media queries into a single rule.
> Each query in a comma-separated list is treated separately from the others.
> Thus, if any of the queries in a list is true, the entire media statement
> returns true.
> In other words, lists behave like a logical or operator.

For example

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 375px)
  , screen and (max-width: 414px)
{
   /* some css here */
}
```

Also, [`device-width`/`device-height` are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-height#browser_compatibility). Consider using [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width)/[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/height) instead, as seen in the example above.